# Find and Paste in different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a report in my office. Struckup in one point, so need your help or suggestions on that.

I have 3 different worksheet contains the "Emp Name" and their " Emp ID". (note: the order is not same order).
If i enter the working hours in one sheet (ie) in the third column, the same working hours want to replicate in other sheet as well. Kindly advise me the solution.

Please find the below as an example.

In Work Sheet 1:

```
Name    Emp ID
AAA     123456
BBB     154658
CCC     178954
```

In Work Sheet 2:

```
Name    Emp ID
BBB     154658
CCC     178954
AAA     123456
```

I have the below code, but its copy and pate whole data from Worksheet1 to Worksheet2 which is already existing in a particular folder. I required to copy and pate the third and fouth column to Worksheet2 from Worksheet1, but the name and emp id is not same as per the Worksheet1.

```
Sub copydata()
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook
    Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
    Dim wbname As String
    ' check if the file is open
    ret = Isworkbookopen("H:\Srikanth\Book2.xlsm")
    If ret = False Then
        ' open file
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("H:\Srikanth\Book2.xlsm")
    Else
        'Just make it active
        'Workbooks("C:\stack\file1.xlsx").Activate
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
    End If
    ' check if the file is open
    ret = Isworkbookopen("H:\Srikanth\Book1.xlsx")
    If ret = False Then
        ' open file
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("H:\Srikanth\Book1.xlsx")
    Else
        'Just make it active
        'Workbooks("C:\stack\file2.xlsx").Activate
        Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    End If
    'perform copy
    Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("filedata")
    shttocopy.Copy wkbDest.Sheets(3)
End Sub
Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim nam As String
    wbname = filename
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0 : Isworkbookopen = False
        Case 70 : Isworkbookopen = True
        Case Else : Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be pretty simple if use VLOOKUP to achieve the same rather than writing VBA code.

Advantage of using formula will be:

1. Easier to edit and understand
2. Faster result and it will be light weight.

Comment: will you able to give the codings for that. Please.. i gave sample data. I have more than 500 employee details

Comment: Check this link and hope this will help you: http://howtovlookupinexcel.com/vlookup-between-two-workbooks